# Revert javascript file to the button in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have separate file of JavaScript  and HTML and I want to revert the button to his function in JavaScript file using jQuery `$('#')`  then I want to send the value of *lat* and *lon* to the database.

https://jsfiddle.net/razanrab/qct5j19z/6/

```
var map, infoWindow;
var geocoder;
function initMap() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 6
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            title: 'Your position'
        });
        /*infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Your position');
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);*/
        map.setCenter(pos);


      updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
      geocodePosition(pos);

      // Add dragging event listeners.
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
        updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
        updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        updateMarkerPosition(e.latLng);
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
      });

    }, function() {
       handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
} else {
  // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
}

}
function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}
function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

Comment: Hey @Roz and welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is unclear, do you mean  how to call the function simply on button click?

Comment: @Lissy yes , its work when i put the script in  the same file , but now i have html file and jasvascript file

Comment: ok, makes seance. I've added an answer, though thinking about it, double check that your JS file is properly included, any errors in the developer tools??

Answer (score 1):

You said you wanted to do this with jQuery?

Add this function to the bottom of your map JS file:

```
$("#locate").click(function(){
    initMap();
});
```

You can then delete the `onClick=""` attribute on the button.

Here's the updated working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qct5j19z/7/

(You will need jQuery included above on your webpage. [See here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp))

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above im guessing that you had the js and the html in the same file and it worked but you moved the javascript to a seperate file and now it no longer works

make sure your adding this 
`<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>`

Since web browsers cache js files whenever you update the javascript file try versioning like this

`<script src="path/to/file.js?v=0.0.1"></script>`

That way all users will recieve the updated file